# Toolbar or NavigationBar Items on IOS duplicated themselves Why?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have tried to implement Toolbar items in Xmarin.forms , but on IOS it's seen wired,  **Save and Cancel** Appears twice  why is this happening.

**Below is the image :**

[image]

Cancel and save have Duplicated themselves.

This is the Xaml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    Title="EA Mobile Directory"
    xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView" x:Class="EAMobileDirectory.HomeActivity">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Save"  Priority="0" Order="Primary" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Cancel"  Priority="1" Order="Primary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Then i added a Class  this in the **Project.IOS**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EAMobileDirectory;
using EAMobileDirectory.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HomeActivity), typeof(FridgeContentPageRenderer))]
namespace EAMobileDirectory.iOS
{
public class FridgeContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
        public new HomeActivity Element
    {
            get { return (HomeActivity)base.Element; }
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        var LeftNavList = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
        var rightNavList = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

        var navigationItem = this.NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;

        for (var i = 0; i < Element.ToolbarItems.Count; i++)
        {

            var reorder = (Element.ToolbarItems.Count - 1);
            var ItemPriority = Element.ToolbarItems[reorder - i].Priority;

            if (ItemPriority == 1)
            {
                UIBarButtonItem LeftNavItems = navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems[i];
                LeftNavList.Add(LeftNavItems);
            }
            else if (ItemPriority == 0)
            {
                UIBarButtonItem RightNavItems = navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems[i];
                rightNavList.Add(RightNavItems);
            }
        }

        navigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItems(LeftNavList.ToArray(), false);
        navigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(rightNavList.ToArray(), false);

    } }
}
```

Why is this Happening ? , please help.

**EDIT:**

[image]

**This is the App.cs:**

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EAMobileDirectory
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static DataProvider dbUtils;

```
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            try
            {
                DataProvider db = new DataProvider();
                string country = db.GetSelectedCountry();
                if (country != null)
                {

                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainActivity());

                }

                else
                {


                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SetCountry())

                    {
                        //BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FF0000"),
                        BarTextColor = Color.White,
                        Title = "Select your country",



                    };
                }
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SetCountry())

                {
                    //BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FF0000"),
                    BarTextColor = Color.White,
                    Title = "Select your country",



                };

            }

            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SetCountry())

                {
                    //BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FF0000"),
                    BarTextColor = Color.White,
                    Title = "Select your country",



                };
            }

        }

        public static DataProvider DAUtil
        {
            get
            {
                if (dbUtils == null)
                {
                    dbUtils = new DataProvider();
                }
                return dbUtils;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding ToolbarItem twice. in page and in page renderer also.

  <ToolbarItem Text="Save"  Priority="0" Order="Primary" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Cancel"  Priority="1" Order="Primary" />

and

 navigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItems(LeftNavList.ToArray(), false);
        navigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(rightNavList.ToArray(), false);

Comment: I'm not sure on what the effect is you are trying to achieve, but it seems to me that you need to remove the original button, I only see you adding buttons.

Comment: Thankx for the reply  @Sunny, please edit for me my code.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, i want to add Items on the Navigation bar but it's appearing twice thats the problem, but i  want my items to be both Save and cancel

Comment: But where do you want them? In the bottom bar only?

Comment: Comment these two lines.

navigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItems(LeftNavList.ToArray(), false);
        navigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(rightNavList.ToArray(), false);

Comment: @Sunny, i did that but Save and Cancel are on the right side , but still it appears twice Up and down

Comment: @Sunny , i have made an edit to the post , check out how my App looks now after doing your sugested change

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, the one at the top , please guys help me out

Comment: It seems something else is going wrong. When you are navigating to this page, are you doing `new NavigationPage(...)`' again? It looks like you are wrapping two NavigationPages in one.

Comment: Ok @GeraldVersluis, let me post you my App.cs class and see.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, check my App.cs class

Comment: Why are you setting the MainPage all the time? Please have a look at my sample repository here: https://github.com/jfversluis/LeftToolbarSample this demonstrates how to navigate and also where your problem occurs

Comment: Ok thanks @GeraldVersluis , let me give it a shot

Comment: Did you get something to work?